# Regulating the volume of SKAction playSoundFileNamed:

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way to regulate the volume of sound played via SKAction [playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed%3awaitForCompletion%3a).

I would like to implement a simple music & sound effects slider in my game. I can easily control background music since i play it via AVAudioPlayer, but all sound effects are played via SKAction.

Comment: You can use AVAudioPlayer in a SKScene aswell

Comment: I know, but it was more convenient for me to use SKAction. Due to most of the sounds being played during character animations implemented via SKAction sequences. I know i could go with runBlock action and implement play sound there any way i want, but i don't want to resort to that if I have a way it was meant to be played here :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't modify the volume using SKAction, so you have to use AVAudioPlayer for  your effects too.
You could implement a custom playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:volume: using runBlock as you already thought, so your code won't be very different then using playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my code for how i handled this problem

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"pew-pew-lei" withExtension:@"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
[player setVolume:masterVolume];
[player prepareToPlay];

SKAction*   playAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [player play];
}];
SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:player.duration+1];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[playAction, waitAction]];

[self runAction:sequence];
```

The masterVolume variable is just some preset variable i have that the user can change from 0.0-1.0

The waitAction ensures that the player doesn't get removed before it has played the entire sound

Hope this helps!

Comment: This code works but the last line should be: [self runAction: sequence]; (instead of [self runAction: groupActions];) and you will need to #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: This works! Was trying to export sound effect from my DAW and for some reason couldn't lower the volume! Weird. This allowed me to use the sound effect I wanted and I was able to lower the volume in code.

Answer (score 4):

### Swift:

Since **iOS 9.0** you can change the volume to your node running another action if you have already runned your audio (*remember that this one  obviusly  cannot work if you have something that run with `repeatForever`*):

```
let changeVolumeAction = SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0.3, duration: 0.3)
node.run(changeVolume)
```

Or you can create a group and launching your audio with the correct volume:

```
let effectAudioAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("electricshockLow.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
let changeVolumeAction = SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0.3, duration: 0.3)
let effectAudioGroup = SKAction.group([effectAudioAction,changeVolumeAction])
node.run(effectAudioGroup)
```

Comment: Grouping these actions had no effect in my Xcode project.