# SKAction.changeVolume(to:duration:) does not work

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I'm currently playing around with background music and sound effects for my SpriteKit based iOS game. While I managed to set the volume for the background music (using a SKAudioNode) I have some problems with the sound effects. I tried to set the volume for the scene before presenting it (sound effects are played by the scene - here to 0.0 for testing purposes):

```
run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0.0, duration: 0))
```

But that did not work. And even, if I set the volume to 0.0 before actually playing a sound effect like that:

```
run(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0.0, duration: 0),
    SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("soundEffect.m4a", waitForCompletion: false)
]))
```

... it does not work, and you can still hear the sound effect.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try a really really small value instead of `0` for the duration.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer: I tried 0.01 (and 0.5) instead, but it did not work either.

Comment: Just noticed that the summary for changeVolume says "Creates an action that changes an *audio* node’s volume to a new value." - I'm trying to perform that action on a scene node. Maybe that's an issue? However, the action is actually processed. Just added an completion block to check this. But is it really executed?

Comment: Yes that’s the issue! The code will still compile if you run it on the scene, but the scene wouldn’t know what to do with it. You should run it on an audio node.

Comment: Hmm, sounds obvious (and works for the SKAudioNode mentioned above playing the background music) - but is it really not possible to set the volume for the scene itself? After all it‘s the scene that‘s playing the sound effect via playSoundFileNamed - if it can play sounds, why can‘t I control the volume?!

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371223/regulating-the-volume-of-skaction-playsoundfilenamed), it seems to not be possible...

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand there's a comment at the bottom of that post from June 15th '18 stating that it should be possible from iOS9? (Unfortunately I'm not able to comment on that post yet to ask whether this only holds for specific nodes)

Comment: Playsoundfile is designed to fire as fast as possible.  Whay allesandro’s answer does is lower the volume for every new sound played, it does not reduce the volume of anything currently playing

Comment: 2/25/2019 - running into the same issue, and I think this is a bug.  If you can play a sound on a SKSpriteNode, then the volume change action should work.  Has anyone reported this issue to Apple?